# creating an adjacency List for Graphs in Scala

Tags: scala, graph, adjacency-list

I have a list of edges, for an undirected graph, saved in `var edges: List[Edge]`. Some of them are.

```
A, B, 6
B, A, 6
A, D, 4
D, A, 4
B, C, 10
C, B, 10
B, D, 7
D, B, 7
B, E, 7
E, B, 7
C, D, 8
D, C, 8
C, E, 5
E, C, 5
C, F, 6
F, C, 6
D, E, 12
E, D, 12
E, F, 7
F, E, 7
```

I am trying to put them in an adjacency List, in this way:

```
val adjList: List[(Vertex, List[Vertex])] = 
      (graph.edges.groupBy(_.source).map 
          { case (k,v) => (k, v.map {_.destination}) }).toList
```

But, it's not functional. Something I am doing wrong? :(

Edit:

---

It is not wrong (my mistake, read my comment below)!

Comment: What do you mean with "_But, it's not functional_" ? Which error/output do you get ?

Comment: @Peter Neyens, it was giving me a map of values but two edges were mixed. I just fixed it :( . It was because I was using print() to debug and it was mixing my values ... I know "shame for me" :D . But you know, I was re-running to copy and paste the result, to reply you, and I just found it. Thanks for the question ;)

Comment: @PeterNeyens, is there a way to get the result as `List[Vertex, List[Vertex]]` instead of `List[(Vertex, List[Vertex])] ` ?

Comment: @Valerin, no, List[T] has only one type parameter.

Comment: You can use `mapValues` to make it slightly simpler : `edges.groupBy(_.source).mapValues(edges => edges.map(_.destination)).toList`

Comment: @ka4eli, thnxx a lot for this explanation.

Comment: You may see the http://www.scala-graph.org/ for reference. Or may just use as a ready to use library

Comment: If you fixed this, you should add an answer and mark it to prevent this to register as "unaswered"

Answer (score 0):

My given solution up is right. Simply, It was a wrong testing from my side. Thanks your everybody's help.